# JQuery: event.target.id does not work for child of child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a side menu with the following markup.

[image: And following code to get the id of t]he element that is being clicked inside the UL:

```
$("#main-ul").click(function (event) {
    var clickedLiItemId = event.target.id;
}
```

The ID `1_0` and `2_0` is a main menu, clicking on it doesn't trigger page redirect. It only expand and display the child menu.

When I click on the main menu, let's say I click on `2_0`, the `$("#main-ul").click` function will be triggered and `event.target.id` will get the value `2_0`.

But, after the child menu expanded and I click on `2_1` or `2_2`, the `event.target.id` return empty value.

So what should I do to get the ID on any of the clicked element inside `main-ul` markup? I need to get the particular clicked ID to do some function.

Comment: post the code with snippet instead of image

Comment: the problem in your code is, you have a binding to the id #main-ul and the event target is allways the element with #main-ul as id.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('ul a').click(function(event){
  alert(event.target.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="1">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="2">Second</a></li>
<ul>
```